# двойная проверка в for

Tags: java

Подскажите можно выполнить проверку так? Или нужно делать две разных?

```java
for(String arrlogin:loginBase&&String arrPassword:loginPasswordBase){
                    if(arrlogin.equals(login)&&arrPassword.equals(password)){
                        System.out.println("Hello mr. "+login+". We are glad that you back.");
                            }
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что код предполагает перебор всех пар логин-пароль? Это неудачный подход. Например, он подразумевает, что можно войти с именем Васи, а паролем Пети.

Comment: @MBo понял, а вообще можно такую конструкцию использовать? Компилятор выдает такие ошибки.
.\singIn.java:28: error: ')' expected
                        for(String arrlogin:loginBase&&String arrPassword:loginPasswordBase){
                                                             ^
.\singIn.java:28: error: not a statement

Comment: Используйте HashMap, вместо двух массивов

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html
The general form of the **for** statement can be expressed as follows:

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

Если вы хотите одновременно брать значение из двух отдельных коллекций, можете использовать конструкцию:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(loginBase.size(), loginPasswordBase.size()); i++) {
    if (loginBase.get(i).equals(login) && loginPasswordBase.get(i).equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("Hello mr. " + login + ". We are glad that you back.");
    }
}
```

из массивов:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(loginBase.length, loginPasswordBase.length); i++) {
    if (loginBase[i].equals(login) && loginPasswordBase[i].equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("Hello mr. " + login + ". We are glad that you back.");
    }
}
```